# Pytest not executing methods under class

Tags: python-3.x, class, pytest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gZxD.png)I have created class "TestExample" inside that "test_crossbrowser" method is present but when i tried to run the code from both CMD and from pycharm terminal, the test under class did not run. Whereas test method outside of class that is running fine.

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("sendData")
def test_verifyData(sendData):
    print(sendData)

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("browsers")
class TestExample:
    def test_crossbrowser(self, browsers):
        log = Logs().test_loggingInfo()
        log.info(browsers[0])
        log.info(browsers[1])`
```

I think, i have followed proper naming convention. I tried with CMD and pycharm terminal. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For pytest, the name of the file with the test is also important. For example, the name should start with test_, example:
test_run_browsers.py

Comment: Yes, my file name is test_endtoend.py

Comment: Please show the structure of the project and how do you run the tests?

Comment: I have added picture of my project structure in the issue description. I am using command pytest -v -s test_endtoend.py  One method outside of class is running correctly only issue with class method.

Comment: so it doesn't start either?
pytest pytestDemo/test_endtoend.py::TestExample

Comment: No, Methods under that particular class not running. Its very strange and i am not getting where i am doing mistake.